# SAP Fiori IOS SDK Offline OData Filter Issue

Tags: swift, odata, sap-btp-sdk-ios

I'm trying to add a query to offline provider as below. 
And I'm trying to add a filter condition for a DateTime property of my entity.
Data types of startdate property both the proxy generated object and the `CommonUtility.getDefaultStartDateEndDate().startDate` are same - Local-DateTime

```
try offlineODataProvider.add(definingQuery: OfflineODataDefiningQuery(name: MobileServiceMetadata.EntitySets.svsOrderList.entityType.localName, query:
 DataQuery().from(MobileServiceMetadata.EntitySets.svsOrderList).where(SvsOrderListType.plannedStartDate.greaterThan(CommonUtility.getDefaultStartDateEndDate().startDate)).selectAll(),automaticallyRetrievesStreams: false));
```

But it gives an error saying there is a syntax error in the OData query.
So when I check the URL in the description of the error it is like below.

> https://mobileURL.com/MService/svsOrderList?$select=*&$filter=(PLANNED_START_DATE
>   gt 2018-09-13T15:45:51.950))

So there is an error in the url because the **Datetime** value should be converted to datetime in OData URL as below ( Correct URL must be )

> https://mobileURL.com/MService/svsOrderList?$select=*&$filter=(PLANNED_START_DATE
>   gt datetime 2018-09-13T15:45:51.950))

This conversion should be done by the SDK itself no idea about how to fix this issue?

Is there any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a OData Service V4 (as the dateTime statement is not included in the filter) ?

So the issue would be not the missing term “datetime”, but the “startdate”-format. 
Looks like “CommonUtility.getDefaultStartDateEndDate().startDate” returned a DateTime instead a DateTimeOffset like required

The correct URL would be 
https://mobileURL.com/MService/svsOrderList?$select=*&$filter=(PLANNED_START_DATE gt 2018-09-13T15:45:51.950Z))
which should be automatically generated if startDate is returning a DateTimeOffset